# Entity attributes not displayed in payload request and response payload NelmioApiDoc bundle

Tags: api, payload, openapi-generator, jmsserializerbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

I am unable to display the payload of the request and the response according to the serialization groups defined with `JmsSerialiazer-bundle` as shown in this screenshot :

[image]

I want to display the fields of `campaignDeserializer` group in a json example of http request, and the fields of `campaignSerializer` group in a json example of http response.
I am using the annotation of `NelmioApiDoc-bundle ^ 4.1` on `Symfony 5.4 LTS` with `PHP 7.4`.
Could you help me to configure display of attributes of entities in DOC API by serialization groups defined in entities ?
Here is the code I tried:

- **In my controller above an `add` method :**

  ```
  /**
    * @Rest\Post(
    *     path="/",
    *     name="new",
    *     options={ "method_prefix" = false }
    * )
    * @Rest\View(StatusCode=201, serializerGroups={"campaignSerializer"})
    * @ParamConverter(
    *     "campaign",
    *     converter="fos_rest.request_body",
    *     options={"deserializationContext"={"groups"={"campaignDeserializer"}}}
    *     )
    * @OA\Post(
    *  tags={"Campaigns"},
    *  summary="Add campaign",
    *
    * @OA\Response(
    *     response="201",
    *     description="Returned when resource created",
    *     @OA\Schema(
    *          type="array",
    *          @OA\Items(ref=@Model(type=Campaign::class, groups={"campaignSerializer"}))
    *          )
    *      ),
    * @OA\Response(response="400", description="Returned when invalid data posted"),
    * @OA\Response(response="401", description="Returned when not authenticated"),
    * @OA\Response(response="403", description="Returned when token not valid or expired"),
    * )
    */
  ```

**In my entity :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CampaignRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CampaignRepository::class)
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("ALL")
 */
class Campaign
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @OA\Property(type="integer", description="ID of the campaign")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"campaignSerializer", "sessionSerializer"})
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, unique=true)
     * @OA\Property(type="string")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"campaignSerializer", "sessionSerializer"})
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $identifier;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @OA\Property(type="string")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"campaignSerializer", "campaignDeserializer"})
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @OA\Property(type="text")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"campaignSerializer", "campaignDeserializer"})
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     * @OA\Property(type="datetime_immutable")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"campaignSerializer"})
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable", nullable=true)
     * @OA\Property(type="datetime_immutable")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"campaignSerializer"})
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $dateUpdate;
```